# Array Enumeration Not Working Properly?

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a method (Pig Latin) and am having trouble with this example test case:
translate("eat pie") should return "eatay iepay" but my code doesn't seem to be making the proper changes.

```
def translate(phrase)
  phrase = phrase.split.each do |word|
    if ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[0])
      word = word + 'ay'
    else
      ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[1])? 
      word = word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay' : word = word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
    end
  end
  phrase.join(' ')
end
```

The problem I'm having is that the array enumeration doesn't manipulate each word at all. I'm at a loss for why that is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you mean `elsif` you can't have a condition in your `else` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each` method simply *executes* the block for each element of a list. Modifying the control variable `word` won't affect the original element of the list.

I suggest you use the `map` method, which transforms one list into another. It passes each element of the original list to the block, and replaces it with the value returned by the block.

Also, you should *only* use the conditional operator `a ? b : d` to return a value - you shouldn't modify any variables. So you could write

```
word = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[1]) ?
    word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay' :
    word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
```

but here it is best to just use an additional `elsif` clause.

This code does what you want.

```
def translate(phrase)

  phrase = phrase.split.map do |word|
    if ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[0])
      word + 'ay'
    elsif ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[1])
      word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay'
    else
      word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
    end
  end

  phrase.join(' ')
end

p translate "eat pie"
```

**output**

```
"eatay iepay"
```

---

**Update**

This is much better written using regular expressions. You may be interested in this variation

```
def translate(phrase)
  phrase.split.map { |word| word.sub /^([^aeiou]*)(.+)/, '\2\1ay' }.join ' '
end

p translate 'pig latin'
```

**output**

```
"igpay atinlay"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `collect` (or `map`) not `each` above. So your code would be:

```
def translate(phrase)
  phrase = phrase.split.collect do |word|
    if ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[0])
      word + 'ay'
    else
      if ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[1])
        word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay' 
      else
        word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
      end
    end
  end
  phrase.join(' ')
end
```

PS: I don't quite know much about pig latin, but you should figure it out from here.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot manipulate the `word` you are running on. Instead use `each_with_index` to  manipulate the array:

```
def translate(phrase)
  phrase_array = phrase.split
  phrase_array.each_with_index do |word, i|
    if ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[0])
      phrase_array[i] = word + 'ay'
    else
      ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include?(word[1])? 
      phrase_array[i] =  word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay' : word = word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
    end
  end
  phrase.join(' ')
end
```